# Covering the space $2^\kappa$ with nowhere dense sets

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Assume $\kappa$ is an uncountable cardinal. Is it possible to cover the space $2^\kappa$ (usual product topology) with less than $2^\kappa$ nowhere dense sets?

I tried to do some work on the problem, but I don't know where to start. I was looking at some generalizations of Baire category theorem, but none of those I found answers my question.

I don't mind the solution using generalised continuum hypothesis or other sentences independent from ZFC. We may also assume that $\kappa$ is regular, if that helps.

Comment: $\{0,1\}^\kappa$ can be covered with $2^{\aleph_0}$ nowhere dense sets.

Comment: Since there is a continuous open surjection from $\{0,1\}^\kappa$ to $\{0,1\}^\omega$, you don't need any more nowhere dense sets to cover $\{0,1\}^\kappa$ than you do to cover $\{0,1\}^\omega$.

Comment: So you take $A_x = \{y\in 2^\kappa : y_{k_i} = x_i\}$ where $k_1, k_2, ...$ is a countable amount of coordinates and $x\in 2^\omega$. Then $A_x$ have empty interior and are closed.